# Insert the values from list to another list when item created or updated

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, custom-list

I have a List 'Product' (Parent site) with column 'IDManager' and another List 'Roadmap' (subsite) with column 'IDManager'.

I need to get the 'IdManager' column values from Product List to 'IDManager' column in the Roadmap list when item created or updated in the Roadmap List.

Note: 'Product Name' column is common in both lists.

Comment: Its pretty simple through SPD workflow.. What is the challenge you are facing??

Answer (score 0):

Lookup column is the answer you are looking for. Try creating a Lookup column in Roadmap list and fetch the values using column of ProductList. Check this video on how to create lookup column:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShLH0mBcA54

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it. But, how to get the data from parent site to sub site?

Comment: You never mentioned that you are looking for Parent site to child site connection. It is not possible to connect Parent site content into a subsite by using Out of the Box feature. you need to add a DataView Web part using SharePoint Designer to fetch the contents. Read about Data View Web part

Comment: To be fair he did state the list "roadmap" is placed on a subsite from the beginning.

Comment: my bad..missed it

Answer (score 0):

You can actually have a lookup column containing a field from the parent site on a subsite using OOB functionality.

The trick is to first create the list on the parent site you want to look up into. Then you create a **site** (lookup) **column** targeting the parent list. 
Now on your subsite you can select the site lookup column and add it to your list.

Mind you a people picker cannot be used as a lookup target, so if your column "IDManager" is of that type it will not work. But if it's just a plain text field it will Work.